# TypeError :Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have created a component for the user profile. JSON data is coming from `Laravel JWT` authentication. But getting

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. same for the name also

```js
<template>
  <div class="mt-3">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="has_error">
          <p>Something goes wrong</p>
        </div>
      <p>{{ user.id }}</p>
      <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        has_error: false,
        user:{
          id:'',
          name:''
        }
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.getUsers()
    },
    methods: {
      getUsers() {
        this.$http({
          url: `auth/profile`,
          method: 'GET'
        })
            .then((res) => {
              this.user = res.data.user
            }, () => {
              this.has_error = true
            })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Actual results must be:
1
Username

Comment: try a console.log(this.user) to be sure it returns `id`

Comment: `res.data.user` is what is causing trouble. `console.log(res.data)` and confirm you are receiving `user` from the API.

Comment: Thanks, consol.log(res.data) is providing a correct object..how to display this object property?

Comment: Done, Thanks Codervine and Thomas

Answer (score 0):

So, you properly defined user in component `data`. And the error you are getting might happen only in the case if `res.data.user` is undefined which you are getting from API  in `getUsers` method.
I suggest, there is no `user` object in response data. By that way `res.data.user` is `undefined` and as you reasigned `this.user` to be equal `res.data.user` it get `undefined` value too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "this.user = res.data.user" we have to wight "this.user = res.data". And this solved this problem.